# How is Clan War Map position determined?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am #10 in my clan (cause I'm farming) but I am #2 in clan wars. I don't have the strongest troops in my clan. I'm just wondering how the order is set up, the only thing i can think of is that it is based off of your defense, but I'm not sure. Anyone know?

Comment: This question is not very clear, could you go back and re-word it?

Comment: the wiki say "Clan war attacks will neither break your shield nor affect your trophies, just like single-player attacks" (single-player attacks being the goblin bases). since a clan war victory is determined by stars not trophies so your ranking within the clan is changing because you are losing attacks/defenses outside the war while other players are gaining more. this however does not answer "How is Clan War Map position determined?" just why your in-clan ranking is changing. to reiterate, **it has nothing to do with the Clan War**

Answer (score 27):

http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/237478-Clan-Wars-FEEDBACK-here

Official answer from Supercell. Scroll down to about mid page. War map rank is determined by **overall** defense.

> - Once a match is found, players are sorted on the map from strongest to weakest, in terms of defence power of their base, i.e., defense levels, hero levels, traps, etc.
> - We do not take TH levels into account. Instead, we only use overall strength of all defence elements in player’s village. For example, a TH8 with higher level defenses than a TH9 will be ranked higher than the TH9 in the war map.

Answer (score 22):

The bases are ordered from highest to lowest strength.

Strength is based on each member’s attacking power this includes available types and levels of troops, army camp capacity, spells and heroes. Along with your defensive strength, which includes defensive buildings, walls, traps and heroes.

Your position has ***nothing*** to do with your trophies, Player level, Town Hall level, Achievements, or EXP.

Comment: And, how exactly would you measure that without XP?

Comment: I explained it in my answer

Answer (score 7):

So as I understand it, rank is based on what defenses you have (defensive buildings, heroes, walls), and not the way in which they are laid out.  It has nothing to do with player level, although level gives you a rough estimate of a player's total progress through the game in terms of buildings and achievements. So basically, moving things around on your base to improve your layout won't help your war ranking, only upgrading or building new defenses will do so.

Comment: Exp is gained from upgrading and building new buildings, but it is also gained from completing achievements, clearing debris, and donating, therefore it is not the best measure of the strength of a particular village.

Comment: some player are high lvl because they just donate alot

Answer (score 3):

Your clan rank in a war is determined by your defence strength, that is calculated by the cost of your highest upgrades and total cost excluding walls. I have the highest level but am 7th in my clan

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it is your trophy count gets you into the war, then the strength of your base defence determines where you rank in the clan war map. For example, your clan has 50 members and you go to war with a clan that has 40, then the war will be 40v40. The top 40 players in your clan (ranked by trophy count) will join the war, the remaining 10 will be spectators. Then the 40 players fighting for your clan will be ranked 1-40 on the war map based on the strength of base defence regardless of trophy count. Hope this helps

A co-leader has the right to select whom from his clan are participating in the clan war. But there must always be either a round number or a number between 1-50 with five or zero at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Clan War position depends on your defense strength. Not the level, not the trophies, but HOW GOOD YOUR DEFENSE IS. :)

Comment: This should be a comment to the question not an answer (the users don't have rep for comments)

Answer (score 1):

Okay the top two answers say most of it for the question but I would like to add a point. So if there are two players in war with the exact same defenses, they would further be differentiated on the basis of their league or trophies or xp.

[How are clan war positions determined when identical bases are present in war?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292342/how-are-clan-war-positions-determined-when-identical-bases-are-present-in-war)

*Happy Clashing!*

Answer (score -2):

As I have understood your question, you're asking how your war base position is determined on war map. Right?

This is determined based on Player Level. Highest level players are positioned at Top and lowest level players at bottom. It has nothing to do with your position in Clan which is based on trophies.

Comment: This is not true

Comment: @Jonco98 This is 100% true.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: My position on my clan's war map is higher than it should be if position were only based on level.  Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Player Level is roughly irrelevant, it may seem like the level plays a role but this is pure coincidence as upgrading/building all add exp and said actions are what you will be doing to improve your strength.

Comment: Player Level, apart from being a requirement for a lot of cosmetic items, has 2 uses, 1) a guide to how much work a player has done (Level 150 will ofcause have a done quite a lot of work to gain resources to build up their town) and 2) to inflate one's ego