# How are clan war positions determined when identical bases are present in war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How are clan war positions determined when there are 2 or more bases having everything upgraded like *defense*, *walls*, *traps*, *troops* and *heroes* to the **maximum level of the particular tonwhall**?

By this I mean that two bases which are exactly similar in respect of *defense* and *troops*, how will there position be in clan war? On what will that depend?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Ksyqo's comment.

Answer (score 2):

The Clan War positions are based on the strength of the base defense. This is calculated using things like amount of traps, walls, disposable troops etc.

Town hall is ignored when it comes to this, which is why someone with a level 6 Town Hall, could be higher ranked than a base with a level 7 Town hall.

But, in this situation which would have two bases with exactly the same defense, I would imagine that the algorithm would then move on to either the Town Hall level, or the [XP level](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Experience) of the person.

Or, as Mehravish Temkar pointed out in the comments to this answer, it could go down to the amount of trophies or league that the user is placed in.

Comment: or compare trophies and league of the two players

Comment: @MehravishTemkar nice idea, I will edit it into my answer, thanks

Comment: Walls have no effect on the clan war position if i am not wrong, but please confirm it buddy.. Thanks :)

Comment: @MehravishTemkar just had a quick look and it seems that they do have an effect on the placement

Comment: Could it not be random?

Comment: @Ellesedil Cannot be random I guess

Comment: It could be random, but it makes more sense that they would move on to other factors so that it's more accurate

Answer (score 0):

I think just random as the majority in my clan are all maxed. I’ve always been generally number 1 since being maxed and at one stage thought it was alphabetical order, that theory failed, so next was XP but that also failed, then I thought it was current clan position, that’s no good either. Troop upgrades apart from heroes don’t matter either as one person still has goblins not maxed (why would you). Possibly duration of when I started playing, but that’s also not clear as my clan member says he started later than I did but really he's not sure. So my conclusion is it’s just random. Once it’s set with long term members it’s just what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am pretty sure it's random..I have more xp and more Legend trophies and higher in all and game play longer. Two maxed out villages. Must be random.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I am maxed everything, and so is another clanmate. I am in legends, Lvl200 XP, but my clanmate is lvl 156 and never been higher than Champions. This makes me think that the only thing being used is length of time playing. He started COC before I did

Answer (score -3):

I am maxed everything just like another player in my clan. He is number one in war and I am number two despite me being in higher trophy league and starting clash before he did. I think it comes down to xp level because he has me beat there and only there.

Comment: This 100% contradicts an answer posted over a year ago